# Different sizes for a struct in cpp and CUDA

Tags: c++, cuda, alignment, eigen

I have been facing some issues using a kernel which uses some structs I have defined in c++. The error cuda-memcheck gives me is a problem with alignment.

The struct I'm trying to use contains some pointers, which I guess are giving me the problems. I have printed to console the size of the struct in the C++ side and in the CUDA side, both in the host function in the .cu file and in the kernel. This gives different results, which explains the problem I'm seeing, but I'm not sure why it happens nor how to fix it.

The struct I'm using is the following

```
struct Node {};
struct S
{
    Node *node0;
    Node *node1;
    Node *node2;
    double p0;
    double p1;
    double p2;
    double p3;

    Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 2> f1;
    Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 2> f2;
}
```

This has a size of 160 bytes in C++, but 152 bytes in CUDA. To transfer the data I'm allocating a CUDA side buffer and doing a cudaMemcpy

```
std::vector<S> someVector; // Consider it exists
S *ptr;
cudaMalloc(&ptr, sizeof(S) * someVector.size());
cudaMemcpy(ptr, someVector.data(), sizeof(S)*someVector.size(), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

which I guess is wrong as the size in CUDA and in C++ are different.

As soon as I try to access `S::node0`, `S::node1` or `S::node3` in the kernel, I get a unaligned access error.

So I have three questions regarding this issue:

- Why are the sizes different?
- How should I change the code or perform the copy to make this work correctly?
- Should I have a CUDA side struct and perform a special copy?

**Edit:**
Thanks to the accepted answer, I was able to understand the reason of the issue I was having. Eigen uses vectorizacion when possible and request 16 byte alignment for this. Vectorization is enabled when the Eigen object size is multiple of 16 bytes. In my particular case, the two `Eigen::Matrix<double, 3,2>` are valid for vectorization.

However, in CUDA, Eigen doesn't request 16 byte alignment.

As my struct have 4 doubles and 3 pointers, that counts for 56 bytes, which is not multiple of 16, so in CPU it must add 8 padding bytes so the Eigen matrices are 16 byte alignment. In CUDA this doesn't happen, so the sizes are differents.

The solution I have implemented is to add the 8 padding bytes by hand, so the structure is the same in CPU and in CUDA. This solves the problem and doesn't require disabling vectorization. Another solution I have found to work is to change the `Eigen::Matrix<double,3,2>` to 2 `Eigen::Matrix<double,3,1>`. `Eigen::Matrix<double,3,1>` doesnt meet the requirements for vectorization and therefore it doesn't need to add the 8 padding bytes in CPU.

Comment: I did warn you about this ......

Comment: Great, that was a big help, it solved my problem and probably will help other users in the future

Comment: CUDA architects strive pretty hard to make sure that structures are identical between host and device.  Of course there are a variety of ways you can break this and the answer points out an obvious path to do so: use the presence or absence of CUDA or CUDA host/device differentiation to do something different that affects alignment or size.  This is a really bad idea, unfortunately it seems that your version of Eigen is doing this.  If the master/top-of-tree Eigen also does this, I would consider filing an Eigen issue.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend using the current development branch ("default"), or waiting for Eigen 3.4 when using Eigen with CUDA. In Eigen 3.3, CUDA is [officially still experimental](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicCUDA.html). If you have problems with the default branch as well, I also encourage you [to file a bug](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/bz/).

Comment: @talonmies I doubt that without a link to your previous warning your comment would help any future readers ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such difference is due to how Eigen is requesting memory alignment in C++ and CUDA.

In C++, `S` is being aligned to 16-bytes (you can check that `alignof(S) == 16`). This is due to Eigen's matrices, which are aligned to 16-bytes, maybe because of the use of SSE registers which require such alignment. The rest of your fields are aligned to 8-bytes (64-bits pointers and doubles).

In the `Eigen/Core` header file `EIGEN_DONT_VECTORIZE` directive is enabled for CUDA. When checking the [documentation](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicPreprocessorDirectives.html):

> EIGEN_DONT_VECTORIZE - disables explicit vectorization when defined. Not defined by default, unless alignment is disabled by Eigen's platform test or the user defining EIGEN_DONT_ALIGN.

which basically means that Eigen matrices has no special alignment in CUDA, so they are aligned to the element type, `double` in your case, resulting in a 8-bytes alignment for matrices and therefore for the whole structure.

The best way to solve it is to force the alignment of the structure for both architectures. Not so fluent in CUDA right now, I think you can do it with `__align__(16)` in CUDA (more [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#device-memory-accesses)), and using `alignas(16)` in C++ ([since C++11](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas)). You can define a macro to use the correct operator if you share the declaration for both languages:

```
#ifdef __CUDACC__
# define MY_ALIGN(x) __align__(x)
#else
# define MY_ALIGN(x) alignas(x)
#endif

struct MY_ALIGN(16) S {
  // ...
};
```

Anyway, be aware of such low-level copies since Eigen's implementation in CUDA may differ from the one in C++ (there is no guarantee in Eigen's documentation about it).

Comment: Thanks! This is a big help and in fact, points in a different direction of what I thought. You said I should be aware of this low level copies. Should I do it any other way?

Comment: `EIGEN_DONT_VECTORIZE` does not imply `EIGEN_DONT_ALIGN` (the implication is only the other way around)! At least in the development branch, alignment with CUDA should work properly out of the box.

Comment: @chtz you are right, but removing the vectorization also removes the requirement of alignment that vectorization imposes (2 x double, 16 bytes, in this case), and the whole matrix alignment is set based on the value of `EIGEN_MAX_ALIGN_BYTES` (`EIGEN_DONT_ALIGN` is now deprecated and equivalent to `EIGEN_MAX_ALIGN_BYTES=0`).

Comment: This answer has helped me find a solution that works fine to me. I'm going to mark it as the accepted answer and I'll edit the question which the solution I have implemendted.